# RestKit : Should the Model classes implement network calls for populating RestKit container Classes?

Tags: networking, model, restkit, restkit-0.20

Which is the best location for "Network calls" for populating the Model classes using RestKit?

Currently i have existing code of  Model class , containing all the "Network calls related functionality " related to a particular Mode.For example a class User (or a container class) will contain methods like "populateUser", Which does a get or post call, and populates the model and does functionality related to model.

Is this fine or workable? Or is there a better standard for MVC design "especially Model" using RestKit.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Generally I use a singleton model controller which mediates access and maintains all of the object managers and mappings. From an MVC point of view, it's a Controller.